# Angular 7 - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'positionChanges' of undefined for MatTooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented angular material. All features are working except mat tooltip. I am getting the following error on mouse hover on console

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'positionChanges' of undefined
>   at
>   MatTooltip.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tooltip.es5.js.MatTooltip._createOverlay
>   (vendor.js:142545)    at
>   MatTooltip.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/tooltip.es5.js.MatTooltip.show
>   (vendor.js:142438)    at HTMLElement. (vendor.js:142263)
>   at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.js:7916)    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:87619)    at
>   ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.js:7915)    at
>   Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask
>   (polyfills.js:7683)    at
>   ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (polyfills.js:7991)    at invokeTask (polyfills.js:9035)
>   at HTMLElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (polyfills.js:9061)

I have installed all the necessary modules like

```
BrowserAnimationsModule
MatTooltipModule
```

Even I tried importing `OverlayModule` from `@angular/cdk`
I am using

```
angular 7.1.3, 
"@angular/material": "^7.2.1" 
 @angular/cdk": "~7.2.1
```

I tried using other versions as well.

I have implemented mat tooltip as follows

```
<button name="groupModel" class="btn btn-info btn-link" (click)="selectGroup()" matTooltip="view company details" matTooltipPosition="above" triggers="mouseenter"></button>
```

Comment: Stackblitz to reproduce an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Please use the same versions of `material` and `cdk`, `^` is not the same as `~`, so correct it and run `npm install` or `yarn install` again.

Comment: Thanks, Mateo, it works perfectly after I implemented your suggestion :)

Comment: Absolutely! I did it.

Comment: It's not accepted yet, just upvoted :) have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a clarification of Mateo Tibaquira's answer.

Worked for me but I had to delete my node_modules folder then do an `npm install`.

Comment: yep, npm sometimes gets silly respecting the package-lock, so to refresh the dependencies is good to delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and `npm i`